# i want to select data where not exist in another table but not working

Tags: sql-server

i want to select data from table where not exist in another table but it's not working, i think there is a wrong in the syntax `WHERE NOT EXISTS` please advise to solve this issue

```
SELECT  CHARACTER6 sales_no
      , CHARACTER4 CUST_NO
      , OCCURRENCE
INTO    QA_RES#
FROM    OPENQUERY(ORALINK_QA, 'select * from QA.QA_RESULTS 
                                 where PLAN_ID = ''32196''')
WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                     FROM   CHECK_OCCURRENCE );
```

Comment: use column names instead of `select *`

Comment: Please review [How to post a tsql question on a public forum](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) and [How-to-Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What you mean by _but it's not working_? you get an error msg? be clear please.

Comment: You aren't checking anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to insert new unique rows, you might consider using [**`except`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql) like so:

```
select 
    CHARACTER6 as sales_no
  , CHARACTER4 as CUST_NO
  , OCCURRENCE
INTO [QA_RES#]
from openquery (ORALINK_QA, '
    select CHARACTER6, CHARACTER4, OCCURRENCE
    from QA.QA_RESULTS 
    where PLAN_ID = ''32196''')
except 
select CHARACTER6, CHARACTER4, OCCURRENCE
from CHECK_OCCURRENCE
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast support

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the relation(condition for relation in the where clause) inside the Exists operator query

```
SELECT    t.CHARACTER6  AS sales_no
        , t.CHARACTER4  AS CUST_NO
        , t.OCCURRENCE 
         INTO QA_RES#
FROM OPENQUERY(ORALINK_QA, 'select * from QA.QA_RESULTS 
                             where PLAN_ID = ''32196'''
               ) t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (  SELECT * 
                    FROM CHECK_OCCURRENCE c
                    WHERE t.SomeColumn = c.SomeColumn  --<-- Condition to check
                    );
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast support